# Syntax of app.use() in Express

Tags: javascript, express

Why is it that some middleware functions get passed in with invocation parentheses (whereas an anonymous function gets passed in without being invoked)?

```
app.use(logger());
app.use(bodyParser());
```

Wouldn't `logger()` get evaluated immediately and the return value get passed into `app.use()`? How come `app.use()` doesn't receive `undefined` as the parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wouldn't `logger()` get evaluated immediately and the return value get passed into `app.use()`?

Yes.

> How come `app.use()` doesn't receive `undefined` as the parameter?

Because `logger()` and `bodyParser()` are functions that *return the middleware*. That is, they're not the middleware handlers themselves. This is a common pattern for Express middleware: export a function that accepts options that can be used to configure the returned middleware.